# Clonezilla modified syslinux doesn't boot

Tags: boot, grub, default-settings, clonezilla, syslinux

I tried to created custom Clonezilla iso with my own parameters but failed. I used [this](https://clonezilla.org/advanced/customized-clonezilla-live.php) and [this](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=clonezilla-live/doc/99_Misc/00_live-boot-parameters.doc) manual and did everything presumably as described.

Here is my **syslinux.cfg**:

```
# Created by generate-pxe-menu! Do NOT edit unless you know what you are doing! 
# Keep those comment "MENU DEFAULT" and "MENU HIDE"! Do NOT remove them.
# Note!!! If "serial" directive exists, it must be the first directive
default vesamenu.c32
timeout 0
prompt 0
noescape 1
MENU MARGIN 5
 MENU BACKGROUND ocswp.png
# Set the color for unselected menu item and timout message
 MENU COLOR UNSEL 7;32;41 #c0000090 #00000000
 MENU COLOR TIMEOUT_MSG 7;32;41 #c0000090 #00000000
 MENU COLOR TIMEOUT 7;32;41 #c0000090 #00000000
 MENU COLOR HELP 7;32;41 #c0000090 #00000000

# MENU MASTER PASSWD

say **********************************************************************
say Clonezilla, the OpenSource Clone System.
say NCHC Free Software Labs, Taiwan.
say clonezilla.org, clonezilla.nchc.org.tw
say THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!
say **********************************************************************

# Allow client to edit the parameters
ALLOWOPTIONS 1

# simple menu title
MENU TITLE clonezilla.org, clonezilla.nchc.org.tw

MENU BEGIN Other modes of Clonezilla live
label Clonezilla live 1024x768
  # MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL Clonezilla live (Default settings, VGA 1024x768)
  # MENU PASSWD
  kernel /live/vmlinuz
  append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live union=overlay username=user hostname=bionic config quiet components noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -q2 -j2 -z5p -i 5300 -p true saveparts autoproductname" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=791 ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
  TEXT HELP
  VGA mode 1024x768. OK for most of VGA cards.
  ENDTEXT

label local
  # MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL Local operating system in harddrive (if available)
  # MENU PASSWD
  # 2 method to boot local device:
  # (1) For localboot 0, it is decided by boot order in BIOS, so uncomment the follow 1 line if you want this method:
  # localboot 0

  # (2) For chain.c32, you can assign the boot device.
  # Ref: extlinux.doc from syslinux
  # Syntax: APPEND [hd|fd]<number> [<partition>]
  # [<partition>] is optional.
  # Ex:
  # Second partition (2) on the first hard disk (hd0);
  # Linux would *typically* call this /dev/hda2 or /dev/sda2, then it's "APPEND hd0 2"
  #
  kernel chain.c32
  append hd0
  TEXT HELP
  Boot local OS from first hard disk if it's available
  ENDTEXT

MENU BEGIN Memtest & FreeDOS

# Note! *.bin is specially purpose for syslinux, 
# Do NOT use memtest.bin, use memtest instead of memtest.bin
label memtest
  # MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL Memory test using Memtest86+
  # MENU PASSWD
  kernel /live/memtest
  TEXT HELP
  Run memory test using Memtest86+
  ENDTEXT

label FreeDOS
  # MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL FreeDOS
  # MENU PASSWD
  kernel memdisk
  append initrd=/live/freedos.img
  TEXT HELP
  Run FreeDOS
  ENDTEXT

MENU END
label iPXE
  # MENU DEFAULT
  # MENU HIDE
  MENU LABEL Network boot via iPXE
  # MENU PASSWD
  kernel /live/ipxe.lkn
  TEXT HELP
  Run iPXE to enable network (PXE) boot
  ENDTEXT

MENU END
```

I deleted all the other items of Clonezilla except 1024x768 for the purity of experiment.

All this doesn't help. Whenever I create ISO it is booted with **default** settings and default menu items, **IN SPITE OF THE FACT** that syslinux.cfg in iso is **modified**.

I see these default params on booting when I press `e` in GRUB:

[image]

And even all the syslinux items are default. What the hell???

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to create ISO by different tools:

1. [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
2. genisoimage, as described [in official FAQ](https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/87_create_clonezilla_iso_from_zip.faq#87_create_clonezilla_iso_from_zip.faq)
3. By rufus
4. By manual method from [official help](https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php)

Result is the same. Why?

Comment: You're far more likely to find success by downloading the USB Boot version of clonezilla instead, as this allows you to modify the syslinux.cfg file without having to extract it from the original 'read only' ISO file they give you. I had the same issue's and found success from creating a bootable USB and putting all the clonszilla files on there.

Comment: `as this allows you to modify the syslinux.cfg file without having to extract it from the original 'read only' ISO` could you please elaborate how do you edit the ISO and what do you mean under `USB Boot version`? ISOs are not modifiable

Comment: Rather than downloading the ISO which is for burning to CD. I'm recommending to download the 'USB Live' version which is a zip file instead. All you would do then is follow the instructions on how to create a Bootable USB stick which your custom syslinux.cfg file on there.

Comment: https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php

Comment: That was exactly what I tried, I put that in the question: `I tried to create ISO by different tools: By manual method from official help`. I downloaded ZIP-file, modified and generated image by `genisoimage` and/or made bootable USB-stick by BAT-file. That didn't help. It seems I am missing some important thing

Comment: This is something i have tried too with no luck. In the end i found success by simply booting my clonezilla from USB instead. Sorry i can't help you further with the creation of ISO, but the USB version seems to work great for me with my custom syslinux.cfg working perfectly too. This is why my suggestion didn't come in the form of an 'answer'.

Comment: Any luck with this so far? I actually didn't use any of the programs recommended by clonezilla to make my bootable USB because i've always been happy with the one i've used for years by HP.

Comment: This one: https://filehippo.com/download_hp_usb_disk_storage_format_tool/

Comment: @Myles still no luck. These apps work fine on stock Clonezilla images, but not with my modified configs. Can you please describe exact steps you use with HP tool, starting from iso modification and till the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was in boot mode.

Booting in UEFI mode, one should edit not `syslinux.cfg` in syslinux directory but

```
/EFI/boot/grub.cfg
```